# Deeproot Pilgrimage and convoke

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Deeproot Pilgrimage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deeproot%20Pilgrimage) in play, and I cast a convoke spell, tapping two nontoken Merfolks. Do I get one or two Merfolk tokens?

**Deeproot Pilgrimage**

> Whenever one or more nontoken Merfolk you control become tapped, create a 1/1 blue Merfolk creature token with hexproof.

**My expectations**

I would say they are tapped at the same time, so you should only get a single token due to the wording "one or more".

**On Arena**

However MTG arena creates multiple tokens in this case.
Taken from a youtube video, cropped for privacy. You can see the two trigger from a single [Zephyr Singer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zephyr%20Singer).

[image: Multiple triggers]

Comment: I suspect that it comes from the wording of convoke, which says that "for each mana in the spell's cost, you may tap one untapped creature", which then creates a separate effect for each mana.

Comment: I think Arena is probably wrong here, but no card has ever had an effect like on Deeproot Pilgrimage before, so there are no existing rulings to look at for precedent.

Comment: @ConMan "for each" does not generally mean that you perform the actions one at a time. For example, [Adeline, Resplendent Cathar](https://scryfall.com/card/moc/167/adeline-resplendent-cathar) has that kind of wording, and it makes tokens all at once.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That's fair. I was trying to find a rules explanation for why it might be interpreted as multiple events, but it is equally likely that the answer is just that Arena is doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

Like ConMan said, because convoke will allow you to tap them as separate actions. Unlike for example [Aether Shockwave](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74208) - if you cast that, chosing the non-spirit option, and it tapped all of your merfolk, that would only trigger once. If convoke tapped all at once, I think it would be worded more like "you may tap X creatures to pay for X of the spell's mana cost".

Comment: "convoke will allow you to tap them as separate actions" what is the justification for this statement? Many existing abilities with similar wording count as a single action. What specifically here leads you to conclude that it is multiple separate actions?

Comment: what abilities with similar wording? I might second guess myself.

Comment: Lands are tapped one at a time for mana generation.  Convoke replaces that action with tapping a creature.  Hence one at a time.

Comment: Convoke does not replace tapping lands with tapping creatures. It replaces spending the mana with tapping creatures. You tap lands to generate mana by activating mana abilities. Activating an ability is itself a whole multi-step process, and can only be done one at a time. There is no process to tapping each creature for convoke, so there is no inherent reason that it can't be done all at once.

Comment: @AdamR.Grey I was referring to abilities/effects that say "for each X, Y". Examples include tokens created by [Clone Legion](https://scryfall.com/card/ncc/215/clone-legion) and life gained by [Suffer the Past](https://scryfall.com/card/c21/155/suffer-the-past). Those are considered a single event, instead of multiple.